# Hackerrank Sparse Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, sparse-matrix

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int nStrings = sc.nextInt();
        String entries[] = new String[nStrings];
        for (int i=0;i<nStrings;i++)
            entries[i] = sc.nextLine();

        sc.nextLine();

        int nQueries = sc.nextInt();
        String queries[] = new String[nQueries];
        for (int i=0;i<nQueries;i++)
            queries[i] = sc.nextLine();

        sc.nextLine();

        int result[] = new int[nQueries];
        for (int i=0;i<nQueries;i++)
            result[i] = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<nQueries;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<nStrings;j++){
                if (queries[i].equals(entries[j]))
                    result[i]++;
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

Can someone help me fix this problem the output is not quite correct but code seems to be right. It seems that there is some problem in comparing queries and entries because of which the the correct elements in the particular index are exchanged that is for this input

```
4
aba
baba
aba
xbxa
3
aba
xbxa
s
```

output is [1, 2, 0]
but it should've been [2,1,0]

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- To be able to debug the program, we need at least a description as to what the program is supposed to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **sc.nextLine();** instruction at wrong steps... You should use it just after sc.nextInt();.

The code below will pass all the test cases... after some changes in your code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int nStrings = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String entries[] = new String[nStrings];
        for (int i=0;i<nStrings;i++)
            entries[i] = sc.nextLine();


        int nQueries = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String queries[] = new String[nQueries];
        for (int i=0;i<nQueries;i++)
            queries[i] = sc.nextLine();

        int result[] = new int[nQueries];
        for (int i=0;i<nQueries;i++)
            result[i] = 0;



        for (int i=0;i<nQueries;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<nStrings;j++){
                if (queries[i].equals(entries[j]))
                    result[i]++;
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<nQueries;i++)
            System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```